# HTML/CSS Image box (popup) adjusting to variable images size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a box over a dark background to show a picture over the content (as many sites do). There should be a dark color filling the screen (OK), a box centered on the screen (OK) with a 1em space between the box border and the picture. The picture can be portrait or landscape, and should be resized so it doesn't exceed either 90% height and width (keeping ratio). I am trying to do that purely in CSS/HTML, without javascript (if possible) [My goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX781.png)

Here is the code I currently have:

HTML:

```
<div id="picture_viewer_container" class="picture_viewer_container">
    <div id="picture_viewer_content" class="box">
        <span id="picture_viewer_content_close">Fermer</span>
        <div id="picture_viewer_content_picture">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,xxx">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    background-color:#F6E9F7;
    border:1px solid #E298EA;
}

.picture_viewer_container {
    position:fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index:1000;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#picture_viewer_content {
    padding:1em 1em 1em 1em;
    position:relative;
}

#picture_viewer_content_close {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}


#picture_viewer_content_picture {
    display:inline;
}

#picture_viewer_content_picture img {
    max-width:90%;
    max-height:90%;
}
```

Current issues:

- a landscape picture gets more than 1em of margin on the left and right side, but proper margin above and below
- a portrait picture ignores the max-height and is bigger than the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use auto with your CSS img height.

```
#picture_viewer_content_picture img {
  max-width:90%;
  height:auto;
}
```

If you need other solutions, something like [adaptive-images](http://adaptive-images.com/) may be something to look into.

Comment: But this would not work if the picture is in a portrait format ? (height > width) right ?